# How use User-Agent to make iPhone download file as a chrome?

Tags: iphone, google-chrome, user-agent

My code is:

```
NSMutableURLRequest* req = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url]
                                autorelease];

NSString *userAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13";    
[req setValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];

NSURLResponse* response = nil;
NSError* error = nil;
NSData* fff = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req
                                     returningResponse:&response
                                                 error:&error];

NSLog(@"size : %d", [fff length]);
```

I prepare to make iPhone download file as chrome. But it doesn't work!
I don't know why...

Comment: How do you know it is not working?  What is the specific behavior you are seeing? What specific behavior are you expecting?

Comment: Get a sniffer like WireShark or Charles and look at your request or setup your own server to see the userAgent that is actually sent.  I have seen that on redirects the user supplied userAgent string is not sent, had to swizzle an Apple method to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

This userAgent String works:
"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU OS 4_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile/8C148 Safari/533.17"; 
Use the Swizzle classes.

By the way.. your string:
@"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13";
Has Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1 in there and that's not what you want for an iphone

David